# Remover sombra entre toolbar e o resto do layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde preciso colocar um `CalendarView` junto à uma `Toolbar`. O problema é que a `Toolbar` fica com uma sombra na parte de baixo, onde eu gostaria que se mesclasse ao `CalendarView`. Tentei procurar sobre, mas não sei quais seriam os termos ideais de pesquisa e acabei não achando nada.

[image: Sombra]

Atualmente, é assim que o layout está. Esse é o meu XML principal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".PontoDiaActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.renanlazarotto.ponto.fragments.PontoDiaActivityFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ponto_dia" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

E esse é o do fragment que contém o CalendarView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PontoDiaActivityFragment">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red_500" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Notem que ainda é um projeto simples sem muitos elementos. Cheguei a pesquisar um pouco sobre elevação (*elevation*) e *clipping*, mas não consegui nenhum resultado.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sombra que você vê é do `AppBarLayout`, pra tirar é só definir:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...
    app:elevation="0dp">
```

Por ser da biblioteca de design, o `AppBarLayout` define um atributo `elevation` e tem uma implementação para dispositivos anteriores ao 5.0.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema!

Comment: Wakim, me tire mais uma dúvida: é possível remover (ou mudar a cor) da linha e dos comandos onde está escrito "October 2015"? Consegui mudar tudo, menos esses 2 itens.

Comment: @RenanLazarotto, pra estilizar o `CalendarView` dá uma olhada nos parâmetros de `style` que ele aceita: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html. Se nenhum ajudar, tem que partir pra uma lib externa, que mais se aproxima do que você quer.

Comment: Obrigado novamente, @Wakim. Vou ter que procurar outra mesmo :/

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso, eu apenas incluo na minha classe de contexto este parâmetro:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Você pode alterar alguns dos atributos da classe Java utilizando:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title")
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
... e outros componentes.
```

Comment: Postagens em inglês não são aceitas aqui. Recomendo traduzir ou remover. Aproveitando, visite estes links a hora que tiver um tempinho: [Tour], [answer] e [Help].